Android using theme values programatically
I want to create a style in a theme and use the values of it in code like this:
        val bgColor = LIST_ITEM_BG_COLOR;
        val textColor = LIST_ITEM_TEXT_COLOR
        val strokeColor = LIST_ITEM_STROKE_COLOR

This is my theme file (theres also theme (night) file similar to this):
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.GuitarComposer" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="ListItem">
        <item name="android:background">@color/component_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
        <item name="android:strokeColor">@color/border_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.GuitarComposer" parent="Base.Theme.GuitarComposer" />
</resources>

I havent found any explanation on how to use theme styles properly in code.. only on xaml
Hope someone could help me on this, thank you.

Check this question, maybe it will help

Hi, ty for responding. I dont need to set the values of the theme, i just want to get them.

Try use this:
val typedValue = TypedValue();
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.strokeColor, typedValue, true);
val strokeColor  = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId)


This did not work, it always returns resource id of 0...
I tried doing this with background property, did not work.
I tried to add the item to the base style and it didnt work either.

After some very long investigating, I found out how to do it right:
val typedArr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.ListItem, arrayOf(android.R.attr.background).toIntArray())
val backgroundColor  = typedArr.getColor(0,Color.GRAY)

Make sure you use android.R.attr and not something else like google or androidx.
A nice bonus is that even if this is on view initialization, switching between dark and light theme does work without need to restart the app!
